# How override styles for android dialog theme?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-dialog

I have android theme defined in *styles.xml*:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="formInputLabelStyle">@style/AppTheme.FormInputLabelStyle</item>

    ...

    <style name="AppTheme.FormInputLabelStyle">
    </style>

</style>
```

and dialog theme where I try to override `formInputLabelStyle`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PickerDialogStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="formInputLabelStyle">@style/AppTheme.FormInputLabelStyle.Small</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.FormInputLabelStyle.Small" parent="AppTheme.FormInputLabelStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_small</item>
</style>
```

I created custom dialog `FullScreenDialog extends Dialog` and try to create it:

```
new FullScreenDialog(context, R.style.AppTheme_PickerDialogStyle)
```

Why new font size `@dimen/font_small` is not applied for items which declared with `style="?formInputIconStyle"`? Are there any ways to achieve that?